# How to make it explicit in Web API 2 for Entity Framework to only add parts of the object that have changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using ASP.NET WebApi 2 and loading in part of a relational database structure into the front end website. This allows the user to make changes to multiple tables in a single store and to also view some extra data.

This mostly works pretty well. It means I can store changes to, say a person table and their related clothes and hair color on one call as follows:

```
 db.person.Add(person);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that, I don't want to load all the related data. So where the shoe table may be loaded, I don't want the laces table to load with info about laces.

The issue I'm running into is that there is an attempt to store a duplicate shoe table to the database even though this was only loaded to allow the user to view these details. I imagine that this is because, I'm using `[JsonIgnore]` attributes to ignore certain parts of the object - it is thus recognizing this as a new object, when it isn't.

I could loop through the object removing any shoe information before call `Add`, but this would be slow.

Perhaps it is best to post a second object that only includes the items that have changed (after tracking these in the front end). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `DbSet<T>.Add()` in EF, the entity (or all the entitis in the tree, if it's an entity with related child entities) is attached to the `DbContext` as `Added`. That means that when you call `SaveChanges` EF will try to insert all the objects in the database. That's why you're getting duplication problems.

You need to learn how to work in disconnected mode with EF. Basically you need to track the state of each entity (i.e. control if they have to be inserted, deleted or updated), and set the correct state when you attach the entities in the context.

Look for docs on  working with disconnected entities in EF, for example:

- [Persistence in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/persistence-in-entity-framework.aspx)
- [Add, Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676)

These will explain you how to handle disconnected entities.